# Sending a list from 1st url to second url in django

Tags: python, django

I have a form in html, django and when i submit i want that a list from the 1st page should go on the second page how can i do that pls help in python

I WANT to send a lsit from first page to second page but it should not be in the url and the form method must be `GET`

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you can achieve this by using `sessions`.

```
import json
def view_1(request):
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    request.session['my_list'] = json.dumps(my_list)
    # Rest Your Code

def view_2(request):
    if 'my_list' in request.session:
        my_list = json.loads(request.session['my_list'])
    # Your Rest Code
```

In `view_1` we are storing the list in the session by serializing. In `view_2` we are retrieving the original list from the session. You can send it a template or can process the list in view_2.